# Issue using toolkit for WP7 - type or namespace name 'Toolkit' doesn't exist

Tags: windows-phone-7, reference, toolkit

I'm going mental with WP7 toolkit import. I've already read a lot of similar questions but nothing seems to work.

I'm trying to using the WP7 toolkit for a 7.1 project with Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 express for windows Phone.

Everything seems to be pretty simple, I followed all the instructions:
http://www.codebadger.com/blog/post/2010/11/01/WP7-Tip-of-the-Day-Silverlight-Toolkit-Gestures.aspx

so, what I have now is

DashBoard.xaml

```
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="768" d:DesignWidth="480"
```

DashBoard.xaml.cs

```
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit;
```

Of course I've installed the *Silverlight for Windows Phone Toolkit - Nov 2011.msi* 
downloaded here 
http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/75888

And I added the reference by right-clicking on *Reference -> Add Reference* and and added the dll I've found at

*C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v7.1\Toolkit\Oct11\Bin*

but I still have the error mentioned in the title

**The type or namespace name 'Toolkit' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Phone.Controls' (are you missing an assembly reference?)**

does anyone know how to make it work?

Comment: Have you tried to **Rebuild**? It's often an easy fix for problems like that.

Comment: I've just tried to rebuild but nothing has changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"using Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"` is not possible. In order to use toolkit controls in your code behind "using Microsoft.Phone.Controls" is sufficient.

But you can definitely do

```
xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
```

and using this create controls in you xaml page as follows:

```
  <toolkit:ListPicker></toolkit:ListPicker>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [NuGet](http://nuget.org/)!

> When you use NuGet to install a package, it copies the library files to your solution and automatically updates your project (add references, change config files, etc.). If you remove a package, NuGet reverses whatever changes it made so that no clutter is left.

Silverlight for Windows Phone toolkit is [downloadable here](http://nuget.org/packages/SilverlightToolkitWP).

If you're wondering how to install and use NuGet, [read more about it here](http://docs.nuget.org/).

Comment: I'm sorry  but it did not work, I installed NuGet and the Windows Phone Toolkit from the **Manage NuGet Packages** but the issue is still there!